# Is there a way to output line separator values in sqlite text output

Tags: sqlite

I've got text like this in one of my sqlite table columns:

```
Mantas are found in temperate, subtropical and tropical waters. Both species are pelagic; M. birostris migrates across open oceans, singly or in groups, while M. alfredi tends to be resident and coastal. They are filter feeders and eat large quantities of zooplankton, which they swallow with their open mouths as they swim. Gestation lasts over a year, producing live pups.

Mantas may visit cleaning stations for the removal of parasites. Like whales, they breach, for unknown reasons.
```

The last two lines are broken from the previous by either a \r or \n.  I want to be able to see the actual value of \r or \n in the shell output of of the column.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you pipe your SQL ouput through `cat -vet`, like this `some sql command | cat -vet` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to directly do this in the SQLite shell, but you can use `.output <file>` to output the result to a file, then use a text or hex editor to see what the line endings are.